# CIE198: Simplification of SMCF (spectral mismatch correction factor)

Tags: photometry

The CIE198:2011 suggests to simplify the spectral mismatch correction factor (SMCF) using the relation of the color temperatures of the Planckian distributions:

$$
F(T_d,T_A) = \frac{\int P(\lambda,T_d)\cdot V(\lambda)d\lambda}{\int P(\lambda,T_d)\cdot s_{rel}(\lambda)d\lambda}\cdot \frac{\int P(\lambda,T_A)\cdot s_{rel}(\lambda)d\lambda}{\int P(\lambda,T_A)\cdot V(\lambda)d\lambda}\approx \left(\frac{T_d}{T_A}\right)^m
$$

Since $T_A = 2856 K$, $P(\lambda,T_A)$ (Planckian distribution at $T_A$) is an approximation for CIE standard illuminant A. $P(\lambda,T_A)$ is the spectral power distribution of a incandescent or halogen lamp with a correlated color temperature $T_d$. $s_{rel}$ is the spectral responsivity of a photometer measuring the lamp. $m$ is called the "mismatch index".

The mismatch index can be estimated by measuring the light source at different color temperatures (e.g. different lamp currents). The simplified version of the SMCF is valid for "state-of-the-art photometers".

Unfortunately, there is no further literature given.

Is there a way to derive the term $\left(\frac{T_d}{T_A}\right)^m$ from the original SMCF equation or is this only an experimentally confirmed statement?
Is it only valid for photometers adapted to $V(\lambda)$ or can I use an arbitraty target function?